# Can I configure networkmanager to set up a VPN (vpnc) connection that uses "IPSec obfuscated secret"?

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, vpn, vpnc

I currently use a vpnc configuration (I connect from the cmd line using `vpnc filename`) that looks like:

```
## generated by pcf2vpnc
IPSec ID ...
IPSec obfuscated secret .......................
IPSec gateway ...
IKE Authmode psk

Xauth username ...
Xauth password ...
```

I would like to use the nice UI integration offered by network manager to connect to this VPN.

Is this possible? It does not look like it is possible to use "obfuscated secret" in the configuration GUI. Perhaps by editing the configuration files directly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/vpnc.8.html
You can use obfuscated secrets in the conf

> Scrambled passwords from the Cisco configuration profiles can be
>                 used with IPSec obfuscated secret and Xauth obfuscated password.

You could also try importing a pfc file (with the obfuscated passphrase in) into Network manager.